# On what site can I ask questions related to copyright?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to make a summary of a book and use it to earn money. However, I don't know whether it's legal or not.

Which Stack Exchange site can I ask this question on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copyright is a legal matter, and our site dealing which that topic, [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) has quite a large number of questions about [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright). Be sure to read their [FAQ](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) before asking a question. For example, it's important to state which country you're in.

Comment: Worth noting that questions for legal advice on specific cases are [off-topic](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice)